# Mostrar datos de BBDD en documento HTML con PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo una pequeña duda sobre el tratamiento de datos. Tengo el típico index que se podría encontrar en cualquier pagina, tras el logueo, redirecciono a un archivo de conexión donde obtendo unos datos de una base de datos, algunos son los datos personales del usuario que son cargados en variables de sesión y otros son en relación a otros usuarios, estos ultimos se almacenan como array en una variable de sesión, ya que son datos recogidos de varios usuarios. La lógica sería la siguiente:

Index -> Archivo de conexión -> ventana HTML con PHP

Repito que en el archivo de conexión lo que hago es sacar los datos de la base de datos, tanto del usuario que se ha logueado como la información del resto de usuarios.

Teniendo en cuenta que almaceno los datos del resto de usuarios como array (cada usuario es un propio array de información) en una variable de sesión, sería correcta la forma de tratar los datos? Es decir, meter la información del resto de usuarios en una variable de sesión no es una guarrada? De ser así, que otra forma puede haber para mostrar luego los datos de esos usuarios en la ventana HTML?

-- EDITO --

El codigo de la carga de datos sería el siguiente:

```
if ($existeUsuario != 0 && $BBDD->coincideContrasenna($nombreLogin, $contrasennaLogin)) {
    $usuario = $BBDD->buscarUsuarioNick($nombreLogin);
    if ($usuario["bloqueado"] == 0) {
        // CARGO LOS DATOS NECESARIOS DEL USUARIO
        $_SESSION["sesionIniciada"] = true;
        $_SESSION["esAdmin"] = false;
        $_SESSION["idSesionIniciada"] = $usuario["id"];
        $_SESSION["nickSesionIniciada"] = $usuario["nick"];
        $_SESSION["fotoPerfilSesionIniciada"] = $usuario["foto_perfil"];
        $_SESSION["interesesSesionIniciada"] = $usuario["intereses"];
        $_SESSION["nombreSesionIniciada"] = $encrypt->desencriptar($usuario["nombre"]);
        $_SESSION["apellidosSesionIniciada"] = $encrypt->desencriptar($usuario["apellidos"]);
        $_SESSION["emailSesionIniciada"] = $encrypt->desencriptar($usuario["email"]);
        $_SESSION["telefonoSesionIniciada"] = $encrypt->desencriptar($usuario["telefono"]);
        $_SESSION["ciudadDesSesionIniciada"] = $encrypt->desencriptar($usuario["ciudad"]);
        $_SESSION["fechaNacimientoSesionIniciada"] = $usuario["fecha_nacimiento"];
        $fecha = new DateTime($usuario["fecha_nacimiento"]);
        $_SESSION["fechaNacimientoFormSesionIniciada"] = date_format($fecha, "d-m-Y");
        $_SESSION["ciudadSesionIniciada"] = $usuario["ciudad"];

        // CARGO LOS DEPORTES
        $_SESSION["deportesBBDD"] = $BBDD->cargaDeportes();

        // CARGO LAS CIUDADES
        $_SESSION["ciudadesBBDD"] = $BBDD->cargaCiudades();

        // CARGO LOS USUARIOS DE LA MISMA CIUDAD
        $_SESSION["usuariosCiudad"] = $BBDD->cargaUsuariosPag($_SESSION["ciudadSesionIniciada"], $_SESSION["idSesionIniciada"]);
        $_SESSION["usuariosVisitados"] = array();
        $BBDD->desconectar();
        header("location:../ventanas/usuario.php");
    }
```

Lo que considero una guarrada son todas las variables de sesión en sí, pero sobre todo la del ultimo punto donde cargo los usuarios de la misma ciudad que el usuario logueado. El metodo "cargaUsuariosPag()" devuelve un array con los usuarios de la misma ciudad.

Y luego tengo el archivo "usuario.php" que es donde muestro los datos de la siguiente forma:

```
        <?php
        if (count($_SESSION["usuariosVisitados"]) == count($_SESSION["usuariosCiudad"])) {
            echo "No hay más usuarios para ver";
        ?>
            <button onclick="location.href='../conexiones/cargaUsuariosPag.php'">Cargar usuarios de nuevo</button>
        <?php
        } else {
            do {
                $num = rand(0, count($_SESSION["usuariosCiudad"]) - 1);
                $usuario = $_SESSION["usuariosCiudad"][$num];
            } while (in_array($usuario["id"], $_SESSION["usuariosVisitados"]));
            $_SESSION["usuariosVisitados"][] = $usuario["id"];
        ?>
            <div>
                <?php echo $usuario["nick"] ?>
                <br>
                <img src="<?php echo $usuario["foto_perfil"] ?>">
                <br>
                <div><?php echo $usuario["nombre"] ?> <?php echo $usuario["apellidos"] ?>, <?php echo $usuario["edad"] ?></div>
                <div>Sus intereses: <?php echo $usuario["intereses"] ?></div>
                <div>Vive en <?php echo $usuario["ciudad"] ?></div>
            </div>
```

Comment: ¿Nos pasas algo del código que tienes para poder ayudarte? Por favor, intenta simplificarlo para trabajar sobre un ejemplo mínimo. Y no te agobies por las guarradas, todos las hemos hecho. Ya te propondremos mejoras.

Comment: Ya he añadido el código, no lo he puesto por que el código funciona, pero no se si la idea es una chapuza jajaja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahora que he visto tu código, te puedo dar una opinión a riesgo de que nos cierren la pregunta, precisamente, por estar basada en opiniones. Intentaré ser lo más objetivo posible para evitarlo.

**`$_SESSION`**

En variables de sesión se guardan datos que quieras tener disponibles mientras dure la sesión del usuario. Es decir, que no se pierdan en cuanto haga el siguiente click que recargue la página.

Para que te quede un poco más organizado el array `$_SESSION`, puedes utilizar:

```
$_SESSION['usuario']=$usuario;
```

De forma que puedas acceder a todos sus ítems haciendo, por ejemplo:

```
$_SESSION['usuario']['email'];
```

Eso te organiza un poco las cosas, pero no evita que llenes la memoria del servidor web con datos que tal vez no necesites tener presentes en todo momento.

**`$_GET`**

Me refiero a que, si lo quieres es mostrar información en pantalla de usuarios que viven en la misma ciudad, no es necesario que "conserves" esa información en memoria durante toda la sesión. Puedes recibir esa petición por `$_GET`, ir a buscar esa información a la base de datos, presentarla y terminar el script sin que te haya ocupado espacio en una variable de sesión.

**Conclusiones**

A lo que te refieres como "guarrada" es a ocupar innecesariamente la memoria del servidor. Y no necesariamente está siempre mal.

Para mostrar un listado puntualmente, no tiene sentido, en eso estamos de acuerdo.

Pero, por ejemplo, para almacenar el `id` del usuario, saber si tiene privilegios de administrador o no con `esAdmin`, te evitará tener que, cada vez que recargas la página, obtener esos datos de la base de datos. O, lo que es peor, tener que pedirle la contraseña en cada click.

Con el nombre y apellidos se verá mucho más claro. Imagínate que muestras su nombre en la cabecera de la página. Almacenarlos en una variable de sesión evitará que tengas que hacer esa consulta a la base de datos en cada recarga de la página.

Espero haberte respondido. Déjame cualquier duda como comentario.

Comment: Todo lo que dices es cierto, seguramente use la parte en la que dices de almacenar toda la información del usuario en esta forma:
$_SESSION['usuario']=$usuario;
He intentando pasar los datos de los usuarios por GET pero tarda más en procesar los datos cuando recargo la página mediante un botón. De todas formas veo que es posible pasar arrays por GET, así que seguramente lo acabe usando en algún momento puntual.
No ha respondido la duda principal, pero sí que me has ayudado a resolver otras pequeñas dudas y a recoger nuevas ideas. Te doy las gracias!

Comment: No me refería que pasaras los datos por `$_GET`, sino a que recibieras la orden de mostrar ese listado a través de un `$_GET` y obtuvieras los datos directamente de la base de datos. El servidor web está para usarlo, no tienes por qué obtener todos los datos al principio de la sesión.

Comment: Por cierto, ¿cuál era tu duda principal? ¿No era sobre cuándo usar las variables de sesión?

Comment: Para lo que está enfocada mi web es necesario cargarlas al principio, es necesario por que en la siguiente página necesito mostrar ya los datos de los usuarios, por eso cargo los datos a la vez que los del usuario principal, de todas formas entiendo lo que quieres decir. Mi duda principal era si no es una chapuza cargar los datos de los usuarios en la variable de sesión, y si hay una forma mas limpia de hacerlo.

Comment: La forma limpia de hacerlo es obteniendo los datos directamente de la base de datos, así no ocupas la memoria del servidor hasta la siguiente página. Salvo que fueran unos datos que tardaras mucho en obtener del servidor. Imagínate que tienes muchas visitas, ¿cuánta memoria necesitarías?

Comment: Con esto me has respondido, así que perfecto, si es la forma más limpia de hacerlo lo haré así para no ocupar memoria. Gracias por la info y por dedicar tu tiempo!